# Basic auth for healthchecks in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, basic-authentication, health-check

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API which already uses OAuth for authorization. I added healthchecks middleware and I would like to make it protected with basic auth so that client which check the health status can simply provide credentials to check the service health.
So far I did not manage to configure it for the healthcheck endpoint.
Any clue how this can be added?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **RequireAuthorization** method. For example:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health").RequireAuthorization();
});
```